# How to have an object(class) be a parameter for another object(class) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I am new to Ruby so I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong or violating.

I have two classes in my example, `Deliverable` and `Pillar`.

A pillar object can contain one or more deliverables.

```
class Deliverable
  def initialize (name, state, pillar)
    @name = name
    @state = state
    @pillarNumber = pillar
  end

  def getName
    @name
  end

  def state
    @state
  end

  def pillarNumber
    @pillarNumber
  end
end

class Pillar
  def initalize (name, mine)
    @name = name
    @mine =  mine
  end

  def getName
    @name
  end

  def getDeliverable
    @mine
  end

  def getDeliverableName
    @mine.getName
  end
end


aDel = Deliverable.new("Deliverable", 0, 1)
puts "Deliverable Name: " + aDel.getName

aPil = Pillar.new("Pillar", aDel)
puts "Pillar Name: " + aPil.getName + "\n"
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
pillar.rb:46:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)
from pillar.rb:46:in `new'
from pillar.rb:46:in `<main>'
```

Any advise on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a typo in `Pillar`: `initalize` should be `initialize`

Comment: I mis-spell initialize all the time! :)

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled the name of the constructor for Pillar

```
#       ⇓ NOTE MISSED “i” HERE
def initialize (name, mine)
```

Comment: Thank you, would never have picked that up.